# Is the movie I Origins based on a true story?

Tags: realism, i-origins

I recently watched the movie [I Origins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Origins). In the end it is shown that there is actually an after life because the pattern of eye of two persons matches.

On quora it is said that the movie is [based on true facts](https://www.quora.com/How-much-of-the-film-I-Origins-is-based-on-real-facts). I don't believe that. I don't think there is any afterlife and the pattern can't actually match and the movie is not based on real facts.

Please tell me is the movie really based on a true story.

Comment: rebirth is a claim, which part of a story based on rebirth are you checking to see if is a true story?

Answer (score 6):

"It must be true because I read it on the internet"

It's a sci-fi story, nothing more, nothing less.

The arguments for or against any aspect of theology, spiritualism or reincarnation are so far off-topic for this forum I'm not going to go through them even briefly.

I'll make do with just this one quote, in direct reference to the poster's claim<sup>[1]</sup> on Quora...

> What possesses a man of Stevenson's intelligence to chase after chimeras and produce thousands of pages of detailed reports that amount to a heap of rationalizations? As Michael Shermer succinctly put it: "Smart people believe weird things because they are skilled at defending beliefs they arrived at for non-smart reasons." Stevenson spent about half his life trying to find support for his beliefs in reincarnation and their relationship to medicine. The beliefs came first. The intelligence was applied to confirming the beliefs. I don't think he is unique in this regard.
>   Ref: http://skepdic.com/stevenson.html

<sub>[1]  (Quoted from Quora)

"is a true Marvel and I can confirm the plot of the movie is not fictional at all because the topic of Afterlife and Reincarnation is already “scientifically proven” by the books and research of scientists like Dr. Ian Stevenson..."</sub>

Comment: If some part of answer is from quora citation will be required.

Comment: I didn't really want to add any credence to the deluded poster on Quora, but quote added...

Comment: Sorry but I got confused. In the starting you say it is a sci fiction but in the end you seem to say that it is a true story.

Comment: Not sure how you're reading that from what I said. Don't confuse the bit in small text with anything I may think - that's the original quote from the <strike>poor deluded idiot</strike> person at quora ;)

Comment: Ok, So I take it as that the movie is not based on a true story and After life is not scientifically proven yet. Thanks for clearing the doubt.

Comment: I'll clear up that the small text is indeed a quote & not my opinion - make it easier to tell...

Answer (score 1):

The Iris scanner and the system around it is shown to be erroneous at points of time. In the film these errors are attributed to eyes that are identical and therefore are possibly a result of reincarnation. The movie shows an element of creationism with that.

In the real life, today, eye scan machines (which are part of the customs many airports across the globe) don't make the kind of mistake that is shown in the film. Like the finger print scans, eye scans are known to be unique. When the systems were originally being designed, the details of the eyes captured were perhaps less and hence could lead to two eyes being marked as duplicate. That is simply because of the minor details have not been captured and hence the error.

The film however doesn't make this the fault of the machine. They show the eyes of Sofi and Salomina to be identical in every way. This is not a real world scenario. The ideas in the film about duplicate eyes is merely fictional and is used to tell the story of a man of science allowing some spirituality to enter his life.